# Is it possible to use HTML5 form labels without leaking globals?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, global

The standard [HTML 5 form label wants an ID to link the label to the input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

```
<form>
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" id="male"/>
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" id="female"/>
</form>
```

As most JS developers know, **[using IDs leaks globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here)** - in this case, `window.male` and `window.female` are created.

How can I use form labels without creating globals?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use the other way:

```
<form>
    <label>Male <input type="radio"></label>    
    <label>Female <input type="radio"></label>    
</form>
```